# Show Toast When Using Llbrary Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toast

I want to using RecyclerView and show images using Library Glide.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Sisop current = sisop.get(position);
    holder.namaItemView.setText(current.nama);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(sisop.get(position).gambar)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.img_icon);
}
```

how to do if when i click the image will appear toast that contains the name of the item being clicked?

Comment: What happen! set the click listener of image view not getting the result?

Comment: @MohitSuthar I dont know how to use Click Listener for Image that using Glide Library

Comment: See @Pem answer

Comment: @Yugo check my below ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this set **`ClickListener`** to your **`holder.img_icon`** like this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Sisop current = sisop.get(position);
    holder.namaItemView.setText(current.nama);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(sisop.get(position).gambar)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.img_icon);
      holder.img_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),sisop.get(position).gambar +" is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

**Update** as per suggetion of **@v-rund-puro-hit**

```
class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView img_icon;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
            img_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(view.getId() == R.id.img_icon){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), sisop.get(getAdapterPosition()).nama+" is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: setting click listener inside `onBindViewHolder` is not good practice.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit yup you are right but i think he just need to **`toast`** thats why i put this ans thank you very much for your guidance

Comment: @Prem yes, I can't set click listener inside onBindViewHolder, MainActivity.this and position going red

Comment: @Yugo use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: @Yugo try this **`Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),sisop.get(position).gambar +" is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`**

Comment: @Yugo happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

i think the question is not really related to glide, this is how you can set onclick listener on a view.

```
class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ImageView img_icon;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
            img_icon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() == R.id.img_icon){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), sisop.get(getAdapterPosition()).nama, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```